# Float Layout Breaks on Viewport Resize in Webkit

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, viewport

I'm trying to create a masonry-like layout for some information cards. I basically have a two-column layout where odd items are floated left and even items are floated right.

This works great, until you start resizing the browser. Even more interesting is that this seems to only be a webkit issue - firefox displays the layout perfectly.

I'm using floats over masonry in order to keep legacy support. Does anyone know what's going on?

[image: Visual example of issue.]

---

/* // HTML // */

---

```
<div class="card_wrapper">
  <div class="card card_savedSearches card_red clearfix">
    <script class="template-savedSearches" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h1 class="card_title">{{searchesInfo.title}}</h1>
      <div class="card_data">
      {{#searches}}
      <div class="entry clearfix">
        <div class="entry_title">
          {{title}}
        </div><!-- /.entry_title -->
        <div class="entry_type">
          {{type}}
        </div><!-- /.entry_type -->
      </div><!-- /.entry -->
      {{/searches}}
      </div><!-- /.card_data -->
      <div class="card_footer">
        <a href="{{savedSearchesInfo.url}}" class="btn btn-default">See All</a>
      </div><!-- /.card_footer -->
    </script>
  </div><!-- /.card -->

  <div class="card card_toDos clearfix">
      <script class="template-toDos" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <h1 class="card_title">{{toDosInfo.title}}</h1>
        <div class="card_data">
        {{#toDos}}
        <div class="entry clearfix">
          <div class="entry_title">
            {{task}}
          </div><!-- /.entry_title -->
          <div class="entry_date">
            {{assigned}}
          </div><!-- /.entry_type -->
        </div><!-- /.entry -->
        {{/toDos}}
        </div><!-- /.card_data -->
        <div class="card_footer">
          <a href="{{toDosInfo.url}}" class="btn btn-default">See All</a>
        </div><!-- /.card_footer -->
      </script>
  </div><!-- /.card -->

  <div class="card card_savedSearches clearfix">
    <script class="template-savedSearches" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h1 class="card_title">{{searchesInfo.title}}</h1>
      <div class="card_data">
      {{#searches}}
      <div class="entry clearfix">
        <div class="entry_title">
          {{title}}
        </div><!-- /.entry_title -->
        <div class="entry_type">
          {{type}}
        </div><!-- /.entry_type -->
      </div><!-- /.entry -->
      {{/searches}}
      </div><!-- /.card_data -->
      <div class="card_footer">
        <a href="{{savedSearchesInfo.url}}" class="btn btn-default">See All</a>
      </div><!-- /.card_footer -->
    </script>
  </div><!-- /.card -->

</div><!-- /.card_wrapper -->
```

---

/* // SASS // */

---

```
// Page Styles for Demo
body { 
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 16px;
}

// Vars
$gutter_sides: 1em;
$borderRadius: 0.25em;
$color-dark: #000;
$color-light: #fff;

.card_wrapper {
  padding: 2.5%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

// Card Styles
.card {
  min-width: 300px;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 1em 2.5%;
  background: darken($color-light, 20%);
  border-radius: $borderRadius;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
  .entry { 
    border-bottom: solid 0.1em darken($color-light, 20%); 
    padding: 0.25em;
    clear: both;
    &:last-child { border: 0; }
    &:hover { 
      background: darken($color-light, 10%);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
  .card_title { 
    border-radius: $borderRadius $borderRadius 0 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.25em $gutter_sides/1.5;
    margin: 0;
    color: darken($color-light, 60%);
  }
  .card_data { 
    padding: 1em;
    background: $color-light;
  }
  .card_footer {
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-align: right;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .card:nth-child(even) { float: right; }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    float: none;
    width: 95%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
}

// Specific Cards
.card_savedSearches {
  .entry_title { float: left; max-width: 67%; }
  .entry_type { float: right; }
}
.card_toDos {
  .entry_title { float: left; } 
  .entry_date { float: right; }
}

// Color Themes
.card_red {
  background: darken(red, 10%);
  .card_title { color: #fff; }
}
```

---

/* //JS // */

---

```
// Store Data to be Outputted
var data = { 
  searchesInfo: { title: 'Saved Searches', url: '#' },
  searches: [
      {title: "Saved Search 982349", type: "case"},
      {title: "Saved Search 823732", type: "company"},
      {title: "Saved Search 000217", type: "case"}
    ],
  toDosInfo: { title: 'Tasks To Do', url: '#' },
  toDos: [
    { task:'This is a cool task', assigned: '8/12/2014' },
    { task:'Another cool task', assigned: '8/16/2014' },
    { task:'Again, cool task', assigned: '8/20/2014' },
    { task:'Again, cool task', assigned: '8/20/2014' },
    { task:'Again, cool task', assigned: '8/20/2014' }
  ]
};

// Compile (package) HTML & Javascript
var template_savedSearches = Handlebars.compile($('.template-savedSearches').html())(data);
var template_toDos = Handlebars.compile($('.template-toDos').html())(data);

// Output (get) compiled template & data
$(".card_savedSearches").html(template_savedSearches);
$(".card_toDos").html(template_toDos);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7612txrr/10/embedded/result/